# Identify the where clause which returns a specific row in select query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery

I'm connecting three tables to get results using a select query in SQL Server.

1. Contact table
2. Ticker Table
3. Sector table

While the contact table contains individual contact records, the other two tables have multiple records for each contact. Basically, it contains the shares the person have (like apple, microsoft etc) and the sectors he is interested in. The select query returns one row for each contact when we send the search criteria like 'Apple', 'Health Sector' etc. Now, in the returned results, I would like to print one column with information about the matched criteria.

For example

```
----------------------------------------------------
Contact id  name    email
----------------------------------------------------
    1       John    john@sas.com
    2       Bret    bret@sas.com
    3       Mike    mike@cityon.com

Ticker  id  contact_id  Ticker
---------------------------------------------------
    1   1   APPLE
    2   1   MCSFT
    3   2   GOOGLE
    4   3   APPLE

Sector  id  contact_id  Sector
---------------------------------------------------
    1   1   Health
    2   2   Retail
    3   2   FMCG
    4   3   FMCG
```

The query is:

```
select 
    id, name, email, reason
from 
    contact
where 
    id in (select ttemp.contact_id
           from ticker ttemp
           where ttemp.ticker in ('GOOGLE')) 
    or id in (select stemp.contact_id 
              from sector stemp
              where stemp.sector in ('FMCG'))
```

Now it returns contact 2 (Bret) and 3 (Mike). I would like to print 'GOOGLE, FMCG' for Bret and 'FMCG' for Mike in the **reason** column.

Hope I'm clear on this. Any suggestions friends?

Comment: Edit you question and show the results you want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would use a subquery:

```
select id, name, email, reason,
       stuff( coalesce(',' + ticker, '') + coalesce(',' + sector),
              1, 1, ''
            )
from (select c.*,
             (case when id in (select ttemp.contact_id
                               from ticker ttemp
                               where ttemp.ticker in ('GOOGLE')
                              )
                   then 'GOOGLE'
              end) as ticker,
             (case when id in (select stemp.contact_id 
                               from sector stemp
                               where stemp.sector in ('FMCG')
                              )
                   then 'FMCG'
              end) as sector
      from contact c
     ) c
where ticker is not null or sector is not null;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, it works and sorry for the delay in accepting. Too much pressure on the project front. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it with LEFT JOIN.  If the contact has neither 'GOOGLE' or 'FMCG' by left joins then both fields should be NULL.  In the WHERE, I coalesce any NULL with empty spaces, to see if the concatenation results in the empty string.

```
SELECT C.Contact_id
      ,C.name
      ,C.email
      ,REPLACE(LTRIM(COALESCE(T.Ticker, '') + ' ' 
                   + COALESCE(S.Sector, '')
              ), ' ', ', ') AS Reason
  FROM contact C LEFT JOIN ticker T ON C.Contact_id = T.contact_id AND Ticker = 'GOOGLE'
                 LEFT JOIN sector S ON C.Contact_id = S.contact_id AND S.Sector = 'FMCG'
WHERE COALESCE(T.Ticker, '') + COALESCE(S.Sector, '') <> ''
```

Produces Output:

```
Contact_id  name    email            Reason
2           Bret    bret@sas.com     GOOGLE, FMCG
3           Mike    mike@cityon.com  FMCG
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/40090/19/0